# AWK--Comparing the value of two variables in two different files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, text-processing

I have two text files A.txt and B.txt. Each line of A.txt
A.txt

```
100
222
398
```

B.txt

```
1  2  103  2 
4  5  1026 74
7  8  209  55
10 11 122  78
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
for each line of A 
    search B;
    if (the value of third column in a line of B - the value of the variable in A > 10)
        print that line of B;
```

Any awk for doing that??

Comment: This is a trivial exercise in almost any scripting language. What have you tried already?

Comment: I am beginner in shell scripting and do not know how to work on two different files....

Comment: If you want this done in some shell scripting language you should specify which and add an appropriate tag. Personally I recommend Python for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this,

I had some troubles understanding your question, but maybe this will give you some pointers,

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Read intresting values from file2 into an array, 
for line in $(cat 2.txt | awk '{print $3}') 
do 
  arr+=($line)
done 

# Linecounter, 
linenr=0 

# Loop through every line in file 1, 
for val in $(cat 1.txt) 
do 
  # Increment linecounter, 
  ((linenr++)) 

  # Loop through every element in the array (containing values from 3 colum from file2) 
  for el in "${!arr[@]}"; 
  do
    # If that value - the value from file 1 is bigger than 10, print values
    if [[ $((${arr[$el]} - $val )) -gt 10 ]] 
    then
      sed -n "$(($el+1))p" 2.txt
      # echo "Value ${arr[$el]} (on line $(($el+1)) from 2.txt) - $val (on line $linenr from 1.txt) equals  $((${arr[$el]} - $val )) and is hence bigger than 10" 
    fi 
   done
done
```

**Note,**

- This is a quick and dirty thing, there is room for improvements. But I think it'll do the job.

Comment: Thank you, however, I wanted the whole line of 2.txt to be printed instead of doing an echo!! Could you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Ok, commented out the echo-line, printing the line from 2.txt instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk like this:

```
cat f1
1
4
9
16

cat f2
2 4 10 8
3 9 20 8
5 1 15 8
7 0 30 8

awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next} $3-a[FNR] < 10' f1 f2
2 4 10 8
5 1 15 8
```

#### UPDATE: Based on OP's edited question:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next} {for (i in a) if ($3-a[i] > 10) print}'
```

and see how simple awk based solution is as compared to nested for loops.

Comment: Thank you for both answer and advice.

Comment: Sorry, but I noticed that your code does not look for all of the lines in f2 and just compares the value of each variable in f1 with the third variable of f2 in the same line. But what I want to do is that for each value in f1 parse  all f2 lines and print that line if the condition is true.

Comment: That is because you original question didn't make this clear and I had to assume sample data and expected response. Looking at your edited question, this can still be done way more simply using awk than nested for loop as in the accepted answer.